# Does it matter if the docker compose file is named docker-compose.yml or compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Looking at examples for docker compose files I found some named "compose.y(a)ml" instead of "docker compose.yml" or "docker-compose.yml" that I've seen. Does it matter if it's "compose." or "docker composer"?
[Awesome Compose repo](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/aspnet-mssql)

I've tried to search for an answer online and tried reading on the docker documentation here but didn't figure it out.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is named exactly `docker-compose.yml`, running `docker-compose` with no other options will find it.  Otherwise, you must pass a `docker-compose -f` option with the alternate name, for *every* `docker-compose` command.

Style-wise, I'd recommend putting a file named exactly `docker-compose.yml` (and possibly a matching `docker-compose.override.yml` with developer-oriented settings) in your repository's root directory.  If you're building a custom image, also put the `Dockerfile` (again, with exactly that name and capitalization) in the repository root directory.